# .bib file for CV

Tags: biblatex, sectioning, numbering

I would like to use a `.bib` file (e.g. created by Scopus) differently - in my CV to create the list of publications.

The LaTeX code is

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=alphabetic]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{lib.bib}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

The contents of lib.bib are the following

```
@article{article1,
    author =       "author1",
    title =        "title1",
    journal =       "journal1",
    year =          "2007"
}

@article{article2,
    author =       "author2",
    title =        "title2",
    journal =       "journal2",
    year =          "2008"
}

@article{article3,
    author =       "author3",
    title =        "title3",
    journal =       "journal3",
    year =          "2009"
}
```

The output is

[image]

In my CV the brackets and the word "Reference" (marked by the red rectangle) seem out of place. The brackets could be substituted by numbering.

Can I control these features?

Comment: Using `style=numeric` solves the bracket problem. Can I also remove `References`?

Comment: Bingo! It solved!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For numeric labelling/numbering of your citations, use

```
style=numeric
```

as part of the options to [`biblatex`](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex).

---

To avoid printing the header/title of the bibliography/references, use

```
\printbibliography[heading=none]
```